# rewriting with .htaccess in subfolder doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this structure of my page:

```
www.examplepage.com
```

in root I have:

```
.htaccess
/subfolder1
/subfolder1/subfolder2
/subfolder1/subfolder2/image.html
```

so I want when user will enter in the URL:

```
www.examplepage.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/page/SOME_ID
```

to be redirected to

```
www.examplepage.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/image.html?id=SOME_ID
```

I shouldn't mess with the .htaccess, so I created

```
/subfolder1/subfolder2/.htaccess
```

so the .htaccess in the root has this code (It should remain the same):

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

the .htaccess that I added in the subfolder2 has the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
    RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ /image.html?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

so what I'am doing wrong in the .htaccess in the subfolder2 ?

Comment: You should have `image.html` or `/subfolder1/subfolder2/image.html` but not `/image.html`

Comment: if you mean about this line `RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ /image.html?id=$1 [L]` I tried `RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ image.html?id=$1 [L]` and `RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)$ /subfolder1/subfolder2/image.html?id=$1 [L]` but it is not working none of them

Comment: What do you mean by `not working` ? Can you be more explicit ? Do you have a 404 error or anything else ? Also, do you have only lowercase letters and digits in your IDs ?

Comment: It is saying that: `Not Found The requested URL <myURL> was not found on this server.` And in my IDs I have lowercase and uppercase letters and digits.

Comment: oh that was a silly question.. thanks.. I didn't write uppercase letters in my regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `/subfolder1/subfolder2/.htaccess have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subfolder1/subfolder2/

    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
    RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
    RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ image.html?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```